# How to solve this heat equation where the initial condition is equal to zero?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, sturm-liouville

Given the heat equation
$$u_t=ku_{xx}$$

With the following Boundary Conditions
$$U(0,t)=U(1,t)=100$$
And the following Initial Condition
$$U(x,0)=0$$

Using the variable separation method
$$U(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nsin(nx\pi)e^{-kn^2\pi^2t}$$
Evaluating IC U(x,0)=0
$$0=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nsin(nx\pi)$$
In this case if i try to calculate $b_n$ i get $b_n=0$, and all the serie is equal to zero.
How do i get $b_n$? Maybe i should solve it as an non-homogenous case?

Comment: Your solution is wrong as $U(0, t) = U(1, t) = 0 \ne 100$. You need to make the boundary conditions homogeneous first by making a transformation $u(x,t) = v(x,t) + 100$ which means $v(0, t) = v(1, t) = 0$ and $v(x, 0) = - 100$. Now you can solve the PDE system in $v$ using separation of variables and in turn determine $u$.

Comment: @mattos : Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @mattos, let $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-100$. Then you have a problem that is set up to be solved by separation of variables:
$$
        v_{t}(x,t)=kv_{xx}(x,t) \\
         v(0,t)=u(0,t)-100 = 0,\;\;
         v(1,t)=u(1,t)-100 = 0.
$$
Setting $v(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ leads to separated solutions where
$$
               \frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\lambda,\;\; \lambda=k\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)},\; X(0)=0=X(1).
$$
The solutions are $X_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x)$, which gives $\lambda_n=-n^2\pi^2 k$ and $T_n(t)=e^{-n^2\pi^2k t}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. The general solution is
$$
          u(x,t)=100+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_ne^{-n^2\pi^2 kt}\sin(n\pi x),
$$
where the constants $C_n$ are determined by
$$
             0=u(x,0)=100+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\sin(n\pi x),\\
            -100=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\sin(n\pi x), \\
           \int_0^{1}(-100)\sin(n\pi x)dx=C_n\int_0^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x)dx
$$